# Alternative for issubclass that returns False for the same class?

Tags: python

issubclass returns True when one class is a sublass of the other, but it also returns True when comparing the same class since a class is a subclass of itself. For example:

```
class Parent:
    pass

class Child(Parent):
    pass

>>> issubclass(Child, Parent)
True
>>> issubclass(Parent, Parent)
True
```

Is there a way to check if a class is a subclass of another, but ignoring the case of the same class?

Comment: `cls is not Parent and issubclass(cls, Parent)`…?

Comment: @deceze that would do it, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is built-in function to do that, so you should create your own function using the operator "and"

```
issubclassn = lambda c1, c2: (c1 != c2 and issubclass(c1, c2))
```

Or

```
def issubclassn(c1, c2):
    return c1 != c2 and issubclass(c1, c2)
```

Try

```
class Parent:
    pass

class Child(Parent):
    pass

>>> issubclassn(Parent, Parent)
False

>>> issubclassn(Child, Parent)
True
```